# configure multiple datasource with spring including namedparameterjdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have the following db config class in my project where i try to configure multiple jdbctemplate and a named jdbc template for one of the two data sources:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

@Bean(name = "abcDataSource")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource abcDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "jdbcABC")
@Autowired
public JdbcTemplate abcJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("abcDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
}

@Bean(name = "namedJdbcABC")
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("abcDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource);
}


@Bean(name = "shDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.shdatasource")
public DataSource shDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "jdbcSh")
@Autowired
public JdbcTemplate shJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("shDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
}
```

I seem to have configured everything correctly in my yaml file:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
    output.ansi.enabled: always

    shdatasource:
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@sh.database.url:1521:sid
        username: test
        password: test
    datasource:
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc.db.url:1521:oll
        username: test
        password: test
```

But i get error:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'somedao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'namedParameterJdbcTemplate';`

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'abcDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supported DataSource type found`

Anybody can tell me If I misconfigured something?

Comment: I don't see anything called `somedao` in the code you posted. Did you have this before and you changed it? Could it be a case you haven't compiled your code/restarted your servlet?

Comment: Probably should’ve specified  SomeDao that’s a repository class where template is auto wired

Answer (score 3):

Doing this way worked for me:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties abcDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "abcDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource abcDataSource() {
        return abcDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.shDataSource")
    public DataSourceProperties shDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "shDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.shDataSource")
    public DataSource shDataSource() {
        return shDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcABC")
    @DependsOn("abcDataSource")
    public JdbcTemplate abcJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("abcDataSource") DataSource abcDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(abcDataSource);
    }


    @Bean(name = "namedJdbcABC")
    @DependsOn("abcDataSource")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("abcDataSource") DataSource abcDataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(abcDataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcSh")
    @DependsOn("shDataSource")
    public JdbcTemplate shJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("shDataSource") DataSource shDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(shDataSource);
    }

}
```

Then, in my main class I injected my beans:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {    


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("abcDataSource")
    DataSource abcDataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("shDataSource")
    DataSource shDataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcABC")
    JdbcTemplate abcJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("namedJdbcABC")
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcSh")
    JdbcTemplate shJdbcTemplate;


    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(abcDataSource.toString());
        System.out.println(shDataSource.toString());
        System.out.println(abcJdbcTemplate.toString());
        System.out.println(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.toString());
        System.out.println(shJdbcTemplate.toString());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

and it worked as expected.

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Why the need to use DataSourceProperties

Comment: You need the DataSourceProperties to load the properties from your yml into an object. Intuitively, someone may think that Spring should create it automatically but something goes wrong when you don't declare the DataSourceProperties. I've already faced this problem before and solved it as I described in the answer.